# Read comma separated values from a text file and create a geoJson file using python

Tags: python, arrays, google-maps, polygon, geojson

I am currently working on a Google Maps project. Here I would like to collect coordinates (multiple points/polygon) from users and extract those values and dynamically create a new geoJson file which I can then append to the primary geoJson file which loads on my map.

For example, a user uploads a file (contents below):

```
latitude, longitude
30.095319, -95.993581
30.096340, -95.993399
30.096015, -95.991854
30.095040, -95.992219
```

I want to be able to extract these coordinates and create the geoJson file below:

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [
                    -95.972251,
                    30.091505,
                    0
                ],
                [
                    -95.970337,
                    30.091318,
                    0
                ],
                [
                    -95.970973,
                    30.092492,
                    0
                ],
                [
                    -95.972136,
                    30.09262,
                    0
                ]
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

read the csv with `csv`, turn the rows into the list of lists that you want, build a python dictionary with all the fields that you want and put the list of lists where it needs to be, then write the dictionary out as JSON with `json`

```
import csv
import json

with open("path/to/the/uploaded/file.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    coordinates = []
    for row in reader:
        coordinates.append([row["longitude"], row["latitude"], 0])

geo_json = {"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": []}}

geo_json["geometry"]["coordinates"].append(coordinates)

with open("path/where/you/want/to/save/to.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(geo_json, f, indent=4)
```